# PHP include not working on very simple code

Tags: php, html, include

I am trying to include a very simple header.html to my index.php but it doesn't seem to work and i can't get my finger on the problem:

Here is header.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header><img src="img/lys.png" class="logo_lys"/></header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Équipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tournois</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scrims</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav> 
</body>
<html>
```

Here is index.php code:

```
   [...content]
    <body>
    <?php //include("header.html"); ?>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
     <?php //include($_SERVER['C:/Documents and Settings/sabourma/Bureau/site_2']."header.html");?>
   [...content]
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried to change header.html to header.php because i read if it's in html the computer won't process it.
I also tried to include the full path to my header, but it didn't work.
Please note that all my files are local right now so it can't be a server problem.
I also read php may be "disable" but have no idea what this means.

Comment: What does the page echo out? Do you actually see php code in the browser's source code? Then the problem could really be that your php server is not turned on.

Comment: When i look at the source code of index.php, i see this:

<body>

<?php include_once('header.php');?>
[some html]

 (please note that i just changed the include to include_once because of what sixeight told me to try)

Comment: @Maude, You don't have PHP installed correctly if that's what you are seeing in the source...

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for my lack of knowledge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments below your question it seems like there might be two issues:

- Either you don't have php installed
- Or you have it installed but it's not running

If you still need php software, you can find it [here](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). After installing everything, there is a folder in it called "htdocs" where you can put your php files. In the browser, you can access this folder via "http://localhost/". So, e.g., if you have a folder called "greatsite" in htdocs, you can access it in your browser via `http://localhost/greatsite/`

If you simply haven't activated php, open up the Xampp starter and enable php and apache.

BTW: You can include html files like php files, both should work, that can't be the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did PHP before but it was a long time ago and the server was already fully set up so i did not have to deal with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

> Please note that all my files are local right now so it can't be a server problem

Yes, it can.

PHP is (usually used as) a server side programming language.

It doesn't work without a server (which has to have a PHP interpreter installed and configured).

(Well, it does, but you have to run the files through a PHP interpreter, and not just load them in a browser).

Comment: Oh wow how stupid of me.
I thought it was the same as html/css. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your file with the header's `html` is called `header.html`, but you are including `header.php`. I see the line above that which is commented out.

Try:

```
<?=include_once('header.php');?>
```

In place of those lines.

Comment: It was called header.html BEFORE but then i switched it to .php which is why i tried to include .php and put the include .html in comment.
I tried the include_once but it did nothing

Comment: if you run `<?=phpinfo();?>` what is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Certain properties in your php.ini file will control functionality. However, using a default installation should allow for file inclusion.

`$_SERVER['C:/Documents and Settings/sabourma/Bureau/site_2']."header.html` is not the proper way to reference the absolute path for your file.

You'll want to use something like this instead:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/header.php"); // DOCUMENT_ROOT represents the root directory, echo this for more info
```

Also keep in mind that `.html` should work when included. It may also not be including because you have listed `header.php` rather than `header.html`.

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: It turned out it was my php who wasn't installed on my computer (lol!) but thanks a lot for giving me advice on document root, i really didn't know how to use it!

Answer (score 0):

Please do not get in the habit of using short tags `<?`, because they are not always supported.

`<?=include_once('header.php');?>`

can be replaced with

`<?PHP include_once('header.php'); ?>`